# eog view generated image via pipe open

Tags: bash, pipe

I have a command, let's call it "makeimage", that produces a jpg image to stdout.  Rather than send output to a file and open that, I'd prefer to view the output directly via something like:

```
eog <(makeimage)
```

but eog instead displays an error: "no images found in file:///dev/fd/63".  Is there a way to accomplish this without use of a temporary file?

Comment: would you consider a fifo a temporary file?

Comment: or maybe just `eog /dev/stdin < ` does it?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731836/piping-ppm-image-to-eog-image-viewer-not-working