# Piping ppm image to eog image viewer not working

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, image-processing, pipe

I am working on an image processing project in C++.  To display the images I want to use the default ubuntu image viewer (eog).  I have functions in my Image16 class which can read and write PPM files.  I know these work because I can write them to the hard disk and then open them with eog.  However I do not want to be writing the images to my hard disk because I have an SSD and each image is about 100 Mb.  I want to directly pipe the image data into eog.  This however is generating an error and I am not sure why.

```
ifstream in("/home/chase/Desktop/moon.ppm");
Image16 img = Image16::read_ppm(in);
in.close();

FILE* f = popen("eog /dev/stdin", "w");
img.write_ppm(f, 255);
pclose(f);
```

[image]

I managed to get it to work with imagemagick display and feh but I really don't like those programs.  I want to use eog if possible.

Comment: Please don't post images of text, especially code! Copy-paste the actual code instead.

Comment: What if you use `mkfifo()` to make a pipe, and send the image to the pipe in the background, then tell `eog` to read from the pipe?

Comment: Does mkfifo write to the disk or store it in memory?

Comment: Neither. It passes the output of one program to the input of the other. It's like `programA | programB` except the bit in the middle has a name.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: It seems that eog doesn't work with stdin. I think it wants a file descriptor or a seekable file.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389521/eog-view-generated-image-via-pipe-open

Answer (score 0):

If you really insist on eog, you can wrap it. For example, a crude bash function

```
$ eog- () { cat >/tmp/img && [ -s /tmp/img ] && eog "$@" /tmp/img; }
$ pngtopnm test.png | eog-
```